Vertically tabset on Rmarkdown
I have created an html Rmarkdown file that has a tabset called Sections with three sub tabsets. They all appear horizontally. But I want these tabsets to appear vertically in the top left corner like this one here.
My Rmarkdown code look like this :
---
title: "test tabsets"
output:
  html_document: 
  theme: null
  highlight: null
  css: styles.css
  toc: true
  toc_float:
    collapsed: true
    smooth_scroll: true
    number_sections: true
date: "2024-04-20"
---



```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
```


```{r, echo=FALSE , include=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(kableExtra))
```

## Sections {.tabset .tabset-fade}

### summary cars
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

### Including Plots

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

### structure

```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```

How do I set this tabset in the top left corner on the html Rmarkdown file and only there without having the horizontal section as appears in the picture ?


The below example looks like the one you linked.

---
title: "test tabsets"
output:
  html_document: 
    highlight: null
    toc: true
    toc_float: 
      collapsed: false
date: "2024-04-20"
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
options(knitr.table.format = "html") 
```


```{r, echo=FALSE , include=FALSE}
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(kableExtra))
```

# Sections  {.tabset .tabset-fade}

### summary cars
```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

### Including Plots

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

### structure

```{r mtcars, echo=FALSE}
str(mtcars)
```


for me remains the same as the OP

I don't understand. What do you mean?

I added a picture in the OP : My yaml section is :
title: "test tabsets" output:   html_document:      theme: simplex     highlight: null     toc: true     toc_float:        collapsed: false

Can you add your whole code? My above code shows how you can get it.

the same as the OP.Even if I change to your code I still have the horizontal section

Provide the code which is changed to mine and where you still see the horizontal section. This is currently not included inside the OP.

you are correct.I worked.I didn;t know the one #.Thanks. !!!
